# text is not allowed between starting and closing tags of an element <table>

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an error when playing with a table saying:

```
"text is not allowed between starting and closing tags of an element table"
```

Table is like this....

```
<table id="Content2" class="createAccountTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 240px;">
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" class="topicStyle">
           <h3>Order Summary</h3>
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr align ="center">............
```

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Where is that error coming from? Why is this tagged asp.net? Why is this tagged JavaScript? Is the error in response to some ASP.NET code? Some JS code?

Comment: Are you trying to set innerHTML for a table?

Comment: Can you include your full HTML fragment? Nothing looks wrong in what you have shown so far.

Comment: Can you post all the table code?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am having the same issue and it's pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, it will complain if your HTML violates the basic HTML 1.0 schema (or whatever you have defined in the DOCTYPE directive.)  This doesn't necessarily mean that your HTML will not render, but you may not be technically XHTML compliant.

You can cut and paste your entire HTML into an [XHTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check for compliance.

Comment: HTML1.0? XHTML? Visual Studio? Talk about bouncing all over the place.